# Function handle as input to the function handle

Tags: matlab

Is it possible in Matlab to create function handle that will take as input another function handle and how?

e.g. I have `h = @(x) x^2`

I want to have h as parameter and get as output function that 4*x^2

```
function alpha = fun(h, type)

    x= sym('x',[8,1]);

    gamma = 16;
    alpha_ = gamma*h(x);
    alpha = matlabFunction(alpha_, 'vars', {x});
    
end
```

Is it possible to create something like that? I want to avoid creating alphas for multiple function handles.

Comment: Yes sure: `h = @(x) x.^2; f = @(x) 4*h(x); f(1)`. No need for symbolics.

Comment: Or even `f = @(f, x, C) C * f(x)`. A function handle is just another value type, nothing special about them except you can call them.

Comment: Your function `fun` should not be using symbolic variables. You don’t do any symbolic manipulation. Code is simpler and faster if you don’t use symbolic variables.